# Unable to create Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've trouble creating a pandas dataframe. can someone explain what went wrong with the code.

```
column1 = ['hello']
column2 = ['world']
index = ['a','b','c']
data1 = np.linspace(0,3,1)
data2 = np.arange(3)
data = [data1, data2]
columns = [column1, column2]
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns= columns, index = index)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line  387, in __init__
arrays, columns = _to_arrays(data, columns, dtype=dtype)
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 7483, in _to_arrays
dtype=dtype)
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 7540, in _list_to_arrays
coerce_float=coerce_float)
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 7598, in _convert_object_array
con=len(content)))
AssertionError: 2 columns passed, passed data had 3 columns
```

Comment: When you say you are have trouble could you possibly elaborate just a tad?

Comment: I was able to create dataframe without column2 and data2. But when I thought of creating a dataframe with 2nd column with data2 in it, I got this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. You seem to be trying to create two columns, but they are not the
   same length. Use `np.linspace(0,3,3)` to make a length 3 array.
2. If you pass a list of lists to `pd.DataFrame`, it will interpret them as rows of of a 2D array rather than columns. This is the source of the error "passed data had 3 columns". Use a `dict` instead, which is the preferred method.

So try the following:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> index = ['a','b','c']
>>> data1 = np.linspace(0,3,1)
>>> data2 = np.arange(3)
>>> data1 = np.linspace(0,3,3)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'hello':data1, 'world':data2}, index=index)
>>> df
   hello  world
a    0.0      0
b    1.5      1
c    3.0      2
```

Answer (score 0):

your object data1 has three elements. linespace creates 1D array, you require 2D array to represent 3 row and 2 columns.

```
data1 = np.linspace(0,3,1)
```

you should create array with 3 row and 2 columns.